# Let's encrypt fallback on windows xp

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, encryption

I secured my page using a let's encrypt certificate. As widely known let's encrypt is not supported on windows xp. For an usual user the error message shown is not very informativ.

That's the reason I want to redirect all users from windows xp (and other not supported OSs, if there are any) to a special page without SSl, like warning.example.com and show the user a better understandable message, why they can't access the page.

What is the best way to do this? Within the .htaccess file (if yes, are there any examples on how to do that)?
I'm running a wordpress installation

Comment: You would need to obtain the user agent string from the incoming request. If it matches Windows XP, then you can do a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone ending up here:

Just to correct the premise of this question: The problem was fixed on March 25th, 2016. 
The [X3 Certificates](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) should work with Windows XP (SP3 at least).